# C# リソースからイメージを文字列指定で取得するには？

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

すごく初心者的な質問で申し訳ありません。

VisualStudio2017 Communityで、プロパティのリソースに設定したイメージを
文字列で指定して取得する方法を教えてください。

一般的なサンプルをWebで探すと、『Properties.Resources.ファイル名』で
取得できるということはかかれています。ですがこの方法ではなく、
上記のファイル名のところを文字列で指定して取得したいのです。

とあるサイト様には『Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.GetType(), "ファイル名");』
でできると書いてあるのですが、この方法だと画像が見つからないと言われます。

ご教授ください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

このような方法でいかがでしょうか。

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("ファイル名", Properties.Resources.Culture);
```

Comment: ありがとうございました！まさにこの方法でした。さっそくのご回答、本当に助かりました。また何かありましたらよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

『Properties.Resources.ファイル名』の定義に移動すれば具体的なソースコードに辿り着けます。ソリューションエクスプローラーの プロジェクト → Properties → Resources.resx → Resources.Designer.cs がそのファイルになります。

そこには

```
internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap ファイル名 {
    get {
        object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("ファイル名", resourceCulture);
        return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
    }
}
```

と書かれていることが確認できるかと思います。これがわかれば

```
Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("ファイル名", Properties.Resources.Culture);
```

と書けることがわかるはずです。